# Inexact coefficient message showing up without any inexact coefficients

Tags: equation-solving, warning-messages

I have seen this message (`Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result.`) appear when trying to find when a function equals zero. However, I have no "inexact coefficients" - all my coefficients are exact. I looked into this problem, and the error for everyone else is that they used floating point numbers, but I didn't. Maybe the function is so complicated that this shows up. How can I fix this problem?

If it is not possible to fix, is it possible to get the "corresponding exact system" that Mathematica uses? If so, how can it be done?

The function for anyone interested is

```
g[s_] = -262144 + 229376 s + 4390912 s^2 - 4956160 s^3 - 24862720 s^4 + 
 29081600 s^5 + 67333120 s^6 - 80308224 s^7 - 98554368 s^8 + 
 120892160 s^9 + 80048000 s^10 - 102716096 s^11 - 33825728 s^12 + 
 47124296 s^13 + 5700652 s^14 - 9795666 s^15 + 486201 s^17 + 
 1245184 s Sqrt[-1 + s^2] - 1392640 s^2 Sqrt[-1 + s^2] - 
 11075584 s^3 Sqrt[-1 + s^2] + 12812288 s^4 Sqrt[-1 + s^2] + 
 39093248 s^5 Sqrt[-1 + s^2] - 46153728 s^6 Sqrt[-1 + s^2] - 
 69393408 s^7 Sqrt[-1 + s^2] + 84210176 s^8 Sqrt[-1 + s^2] + 
 65260928 s^9 Sqrt[-1 + s^2] - 82670016 s^10 Sqrt[-1 + s^2] - 
 30979392 s^11 Sqrt[-1 + s^2] + 42412512 s^12 Sqrt[-1 + s^2] + 
 5701556 s^13 Sqrt[-1 + s^2] - 9553152 s^14 Sqrt[-1 + s^2] + 
 486204 s^16 Sqrt[-1 + s^2] + 
 131072 Sqrt[4 - s^2 - 4 s Sqrt[-1 + s^2]] - 
 114688 s Sqrt[4 - s^2 - 4 s Sqrt[-1 + s^2]] - 
 1916928 s^2 Sqrt[4 - s^2 - 4 s Sqrt[-1 + s^2]] + 
 2158592 s^3 Sqrt[4 - s^2 - 4 s Sqrt[-1 + s^2]] + 
 9879552 s^4 Sqrt[4 - s^2 - 4 s Sqrt[-1 + s^2]] - 
 11588608 s^5 Sqrt[4 - s^2 - 4 s Sqrt[-1 + s^2]] - 
 24290560 s^6 Sqrt[4 - s^2 - 4 s Sqrt[-1 + s^2]] + 
 29032704 s^7 Sqrt[4 - s^2 - 4 s Sqrt[-1 + s^2]] + 
 31443520 s^8 Sqrt[4 - s^2 - 4 s Sqrt[-1 + s^2]] - 
 38716736 s^9 Sqrt[4 - s^2 - 4 s Sqrt[-1 + s^2]] - 
 21446992 s^10 Sqrt[4 - s^2 - 4 s Sqrt[-1 + s^2]] + 
 28044736 s^11 Sqrt[4 - s^2 - 4 s Sqrt[-1 + s^2]] + 
 6775772 s^12 Sqrt[4 - s^2 - 4 s Sqrt[-1 + s^2]] - 
 10132796 s^13 Sqrt[4 - s^2 - 4 s Sqrt[-1 + s^2]] - 
 554458 s^14 Sqrt[4 - s^2 - 4 s Sqrt[-1 + s^2]] + 
 1297852 s^15 Sqrt[4 - s^2 - 4 s Sqrt[-1 + s^2]] - 
 557056 s Sqrt[-4 + 5 s^2 - s^4 + 4 s Sqrt[-1 + s^2] - 
   4 s^3 Sqrt[-1 + s^2]] + 
 638976 s^2 Sqrt[-4 + 5 s^2 - s^4 + 4 s Sqrt[-1 + s^2] - 
   4 s^3 Sqrt[-1 + s^2]] + 
 4579328 s^3 Sqrt[-4 + 5 s^2 - s^4 + 4 s Sqrt[-1 + s^2] - 
   4 s^3 Sqrt[-1 + s^2]] - 
 5326848 s^4 Sqrt[-4 + 5 s^2 - s^4 + 4 s Sqrt[-1 + s^2] - 
   4 s^3 Sqrt[-1 + s^2]] - 
 14688768 s^5 Sqrt[-4 + 5 s^2 - s^4 + 4 s Sqrt[-1 + s^2] - 
   4 s^3 Sqrt[-1 + s^2]] + 
 17385984 s^6 Sqrt[-4 + 5 s^2 - s^4 + 4 s Sqrt[-1 + s^2] - 
   4 s^3 Sqrt[-1 + s^2]] + 
 23093120 s^7 Sqrt[-4 + 5 s^2 - s^4 + 4 s Sqrt[-1 + s^2] - 
   4 s^3 Sqrt[-1 + s^2]] - 
 28069760 s^8 Sqrt[-4 + 5 s^2 - s^4 + 4 s Sqrt[-1 + s^2] - 
   4 s^3 Sqrt[-1 + s^2]] - 
 18266080 s^9 Sqrt[-4 + 5 s^2 - s^4 + 4 s Sqrt[-1 + s^2] - 
   4 s^3 Sqrt[-1 + s^2]] + 
 23458560 s^10 Sqrt[-4 + 5 s^2 - s^4 + 4 s Sqrt[-1 + s^2] - 
   4 s^3 Sqrt[-1 + s^2]] + 
 6499368 s^11 Sqrt[-4 + 5 s^2 - s^4 + 4 s Sqrt[-1 + s^2] - 
   4 s^3 Sqrt[-1 + s^2]] - 
 9483360 s^12 Sqrt[-4 + 5 s^2 - s^4 + 4 s Sqrt[-1 + s^2] - 
   4 s^3 Sqrt[-1 + s^2]] - 
 554648 s^13 Sqrt[-4 + 5 s^2 - s^4 + 4 s Sqrt[-1 + s^2] - 
   4 s^3 Sqrt[-1 + s^2]] + 
 1297874 s^14 Sqrt[-4 + 5 s^2 - s^4 + 4 s Sqrt[-1 + s^2] - 
   4 s^3 Sqrt[-1 + s^2]]
```

Comment: I'm not seeing that message. It's taking a long time, though. What, exactly, was your `Solve` expression?

Comment: Are you interested in all solutions, or just real solutions?

Comment: @JohnDoty, my ```Solve``` expression was ```Solve[g[s] == 0, s, Reals```.

Comment: @CarlWoll, just real solutions.

Comment: When I use `Solve[g[s] == 0, s, Reals]` I get real solutions with no messages. What Mathematica version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure that there are not any old definitions for `g`

```
Clear[g]
```

The definition for `g` can be shortened by defining common subexpressions.

```
g[s_] := Module[
   {sr1 = Sqrt[s^2 - 1], sr2, sr3},
   sr2 = Sqrt[4 - s^2 - 4 s sr1];
   sr3 = Sqrt[-4 + 5 s^2 - s^4 + 4 s sr1 - 4 s^3 sr1];
   -262144 + 229376 s + 4390912 s^2 - 4956160 s^3 - 24862720 s^4 + 
    29081600 s^5 + 67333120 s^6 - 80308224 s^7 - 98554368 s^8 + 
    120892160 s^9 + 80048000 s^10 - 102716096 s^11 - 33825728 s^12 + 
    47124296 s^13 + 5700652 s^14 - 9795666 s^15 + 486201 s^17 + 
    1245184 s sr1 - 1392640 s^2 sr1 - 11075584 s^3 sr1 + 12812288 s^4 sr1 + 
    39093248 s^5 sr1 - 46153728 s^6 sr1 - 69393408 s^7 sr1 + 
    84210176 s^8 sr1 + 65260928 s^9 sr1 - 82670016 s^10 sr1 - 
    30979392 s^11 sr1 + 42412512 s^12 sr1 + 5701556 s^13 sr1 - 
    9553152 s^14 sr1 + 486204 s^16 sr1 + 131072 sr2 - 114688 s sr2 - 
    1916928 s^2 sr2 + 2158592 s^3 sr2 + 9879552 s^4 sr2 - 11588608 s^5 sr2 - 
    24290560 s^6 sr2 + 29032704 s^7 sr2 + 31443520 s^8 sr2 - 
    38716736 s^9 sr2 - 21446992 s^10 sr2 + 28044736 s^11 sr2 + 
    6775772 s^12 sr2 - 10132796 s^13 sr2 - 554458 s^14 sr2 + 
    1297852 s^15 sr2 - 557056 s sr3 + 638976 s^2 sr3 + 4579328 s^3 sr3 - 
    5326848 s^4 sr3 - 14688768 s^5 sr3 + 17385984 s^6 sr3 + 
    23093120 s^7 sr3 - 28069760 s^8 sr3 - 18266080 s^9 sr3 + 
    23458560 s^10 sr3 + 6499368 s^11 sr3 - 9483360 s^12 sr3 - 
    554648 s^13 sr3 + 1297874 s^14 sr3];
```

The real roots are confined to

```
FunctionDomain[g[s], s]

(* s <= -1 || 1 <= s <= 2/Sqrt[3] *)
```

There are six real roots

```
soln = Solve[g[s] == 0, s, Reals] // SortBy[#, N[#] &] &
```

[image]

Only four of these roots are distinct

```
soln2 = DeleteDuplicates[soln]
```

[image]

```
soln2 // N

(*b{{s -> -3.09518}, {s -> -1.60486}, {s -> 1.1473}, {s -> 1.15185}} *)
```